# Macro Copying from wrong file

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on macro and using below code, basically i am checking value in "Sheet2" and if I find value, then I am copying corresponding value from column 33 of the same sheet Sheet2 and pasting it in Sheet3.

Instead of copying the values from Sheet2, the values are copying it from Sheet1. Any help is appreciated.

```
     If Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value = "check value" Then
ival= Cells(i, 5).Value
B = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(i, 1).Value = ival
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all of your ranges are scoped to a specific sheet, or they default to the active sheet

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    If .Cells(i, 4).Value = "check value" Then
        Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).value = _
                         .Cells(i, 5).Value
    End If
End With
```